# Create LazyVerticalGrid based off enum

Tags: gridview, foreach, android-jetpack-compose, lazy-loading

I've created an enum, and I want to display all the cases in this enum in a LazyVerticalGrid of buttons.  However, when I use `.forEach`, all the buttons show the last value in the enum, instead of all the unique values.  What do I need to do to resolve this?

```
enum class ColorsEnum(val order: Int, val rawValue: String) {
    red(0, "Red"),
    orange(1,"Orange"),
    yellow(2, "Yellow"),
    green(3, "Green"),
    blue(4, "Blue")

}



@Composable
fun LazyGridView() {

    var selectedColors by remember { mutableStateOf(arrayListOf<String>()) }
    var selectedColorsText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    )
    {

        Text("Selected Colors: $selectedColorsText")


        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(ColorsEnum.values().size) {

                ColorsEnum.values().forEach { color ->

                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            if (selectedColors.contains(color.rawValue)) {
                                selectedColors.remove(color.rawValue)
                                selectedColorsText = selectedColors.joinToString(", ")
                            } else {
                                selectedColors.add(color.rawValue)
                                selectedColorsText = selectedColors.joinToString(", ")
                            }
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .border(
                                width = 1.dp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                            )
                            .background(
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                                color = Color.White
                            ),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.White
                        ),

                        ) {

                        Text(
                            text = color.rawValue,
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            ),
                        )


                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating twice over your items, when you use `items(colorsEnum.values().size)` this iterates over the items, then you do a 2nd iteration within the `items`. You have to remove 1 of the iterations, as shown here

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyGridView() {

    var selectedColors by remember { mutableStateOf(arrayListOf<String>()) }
    var selectedColorsText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    )
    {

        Text("Selected Colors: $selectedColorsText")


        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(ColorsEnum.values()) { color ->

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        if (selectedColors.contains(color.rawValue)) {
                            selectedColors.remove(color.rawValue)
                            selectedColorsText = selectedColors.joinToString(", ")
                        } else {
                            selectedColors.add(color.rawValue)
                            selectedColorsText = selectedColors.joinToString(", ")
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                        )
                        .background(
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                            color = Color.White
                        ),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        containerColor = Color.Blue
                    ),

                    ) {

                    Text(
                        text = color.rawValue,
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        ),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```